# Rules to allow admin to read all users in firebase realtime database

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I intend to create a Panel with Cards showing the (Name, Points, Balance) of my users.
But I'm facing a problem, I don't know if and in the Firebase rules or in my Javascript to display the values.

I want to allow **jNKXLBj39Kdd9vcRAcQ6xl4dzws1** to read and write to the database

**My rules in Firebase**

```
{
    "rules": {
        "admin": {
            "$uid": {
            ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).val() == 'jNKXLBj39Kdd9vcRAcQ6xl4dzws1'",
            ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).val() == 'jNKXLBj39Kdd9vcRAcQ6xl4dzws1'"
            }
        },
        "users": {
            "$uid": {
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**My code in website**

```
 uid = user.uid;
    firebase.database().ref('users').child(uid).on('child_added', function (snapshot) {

        function mascara(v) {
            v = v.replace(/\D/g, "");
            v = new String(Number(v));
            var len = v.length;
            if (1 == len)
                v = v.replace(/(\d)/, "0,0$1");
            else if (2 == len)
                v = v.replace(/(\d)/, "0,$1");
            else if (len > 2) {
                v = v.replace(/(\d{2})$/, ',$1');
                if (len > 5) {
                    var x = len - 5,
                        er = new RegExp('(\\d{' + x + '})(\\d)');
                    v = v.replace(er, '$1.$2');
                }
            }
            return v;
        }

        var data =
            "<div class='card mx-1 my-1'>" +
            "<div class='card-body'>" +
            "<h5 class='card-title'>" + snapshot.child('current_username').val() + "</h5>" +
            "<h6 class='card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted'>" + snapshot.child('current_points').val() + "</h6>" +
            "<p class='card-text'>R$ " + (mascara('' + snapshot.child('current_points').val() + '')) + "</p>" +
            "</div>" +
            "</div>";
        $("#poster").html($("#poster").html() + data);
    });

});
```

**My result in dashboard**

[image]

The expected result is several cards with (name, points, balance)

Comment: Where is `user` defined in your ode?

Comment: I did not understand the question

Comment: You have a line `uid = user.uid;`. Where does the `user` in this line come from? Without seeing that in the code, we have no way to know what it is. I'd recommend studying [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because copy/pasting snippets from your larger app into a question is not always the best way to ensure we can help you.